# Latte (Nette) PHP framework - disable escaping globally (automatically add "noescape")

Tags: php, latte

I am using [Latte](https://latte.nette.org/) framework to generate Email templates in my application. I don't need escaping in variables used in template because I use it for inline CSS styling that escaping incorrectly.
To avoid escaping I need to use:

```
{$style['.ei-section-rows-wrapper']|noescape}
```

I have a lot of tags with inline styles and adding "|noescape" everywhere breaks readability of HTML template file.

Is this possible to globally set some configuration for Latte framework to NOT escape anything in my template? I assume I can set some params after this code:

```
$latte = new Latte\Engine;

// Add some custom filter to $latte to disable escaping?..

$email_template = $latte->renderToString(....);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no official way how to turn off auto-escaping in Nette framework yet.

Answer (score 0):

`{contentType text}` turns off escaping completely; see https://latte.nette.org/en/tags#toc-contenttype